# "Winding number", Chern character and relative signatures of the metric

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

**Anyone answer with good explanation is appreciated.**

In differential geometry, we discuss about topological quantities like characteristic classes.

For example, the first Chern character of some curvature 2-form $F=dA$ in $2D$,
$$ \int F = \frac{1}{2}\int F_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}\wedge dx^{\nu}=\frac{1}{2}\int(\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}-\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu})dx^{\mu}\wedge dx^{\nu} $$

Another example is the "winding number" in $3D$,
$$ \frac{1}{24\pi^2}\int(U^{-1}dU)^3$$

My questions is, ***does the relative signature of the metric affect these quantities?***

***If yes, How?***

***If no, why and how to understand it intuitively?***

For instance, one can choose a metric $[g_{\mu\nu}]=\mbox{diag}\{-1,1\}$ or $\mbox{diag}\{1,1\}$ in $2D$. (Also different relative signs in $3D$.) It seems that it does not change the explicit expression of the Chern character.  (Please tell me if I am wrong here.)

Comment: No changes to the metric whatsoever affect these quantities. That's part of what it means for something to be topological.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Is that true for even flipping the sign of some entries of the metric ?

Comment: In general you can't just flip the sign of some entries of the metric; there are topological obstructions to manifolds having metrics of indefinite signature. But when this is possible, yes.

Comment: Perhaps the topological obstructions you just mentioned are important. Could you please provide some details on that? Your reply/answer is appreciated.

Comment: For example, it turns out that if a closed $n$-manifold (without boundary) admits a metric of signature $(n-1, 1)$, then its Euler characteristic is zero. In particular, spheres of even dimension don't admit such metrics.

Comment: Thank you very much. where can I look up related information?

Answer (score 2):

A topological  property does not depend on higher level structures like a metric or a connection. In fact the Chern number is even independent of the connection you use to calculate it (there are connections which are not induced by a metric). One way of seeing this would be to look at a purely topological definition of the quantities you are looking at. Another is to realise that in the expressions you are using the metric does not appear anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am more comfortable with it right now. I was quite sure that topological properties does not depend on the metric. However, the geometry of Minkowski space is very different from Eucildean space. How should I convince one that topological quantities do not care about the relative signs of the metric?